# rsync include all directories and certain subdirectories and *.java of the last sub

Tags: linux, command-line, rsync

I am trying to rsync include all directories but only one of each of those subdirectories which contain certain files. For example,

rsync -auvz --include '*' --include '*/certain_sub/' --include '*/certain_sub/*.java' --exclude '*' source dest

But this gives me all the directories and subs with all their files, since I include all in my first include, I take it. 
To explain more clearly, there are a bunch of students and each have all their lab and homework assignments in their own directories. I want to grab the relevant assignment's subdirectory (e.g., homework09) and all that sub's files.
I am, rather green, with rsync, but this would help me sort through hundreds of files and save me a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

Using simple `--include` and `--exclude` rules will not work here. But rsync offers `--filter` as well.

I think `rsync -ruvpgot --filter '+ *.java' certain_sub/ dest/` will do what you want ie. it copies all directories, even empty ones, but within directories only files matching the pattern "*.java" are copied. See more examples from `man rsync` under heading FILTER RULES.